# How to make a Discord bot join a voice channel and play an audio file when someone joins a voice chat

Tags: python-3.x, audio, discord.py

### My Current Project

I'm trying to make a Discord bot that plays a specific audio file(.mp3 or .ogg) when someone joins a Discord voice chat.

### My Problem

I have no idea how to pull that off.

Comment: Im not sure that it can always be connected to a channel, at least with what I've experienced

Comment: Well, that's true. But could I make something that joins a certain voice chat in the server when another members joins it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work. You have to install ffmpeg and install the required modules but tell me if you have any problems.

```py
import discord
import audioread
import time

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member: discord.Member, before, after):
#replace this with the path to your audio file
    path = r"/path/to/file.mp3"

    vc_before = before.channel
    vc_after = after.channel
    if vc_before == vc_after:
        return
    if vc_before is None:
        channel = member.voice.channel
        vc = await channel.connect()
        sleep(.5)
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(path))
        with audioread.audio_open(path) as f:
            #Start Playing
            sleep(f.duration)
        await vc.disconnect()

    elif vc_after is None:
        return
    else:
        channel = member.voice.channel
        vc = await channel.connect()
        sleep(.5)
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(path))
        with audioread.audio_open(path) as f:
            #Start Playing
            sleep(f.duration)
        await vc.disconnect()
```

Comment: I tried this code. I put it with some other code, and got the bot to come online, but it won't join a voice chat. The ID of the voice chat is 663452123299840017, if that helps. And here is my code so far: https://Code--agentlonestar.repl.co

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, by the way.

Comment: And it will only join a voice channel when a user joins a voice channel

Comment: It has no errors in console, and truthfully not even any console output. And as for joining a voice chat, the bot comes online when I run the .py file, but it doesn't join a voice chat at all. I tried all of the voice chats in the server, and it never joined them.

Comment: Could you make a pastebin with your code so that I could look at it?

Comment: Have you tried putting `client.run("Stonks")` at the very last line?

Comment: Ok, so I got it to join a voice chat, but it still won't play the file. Here's a link to my console output: https://pastebin.com/bLi1aqBk . And here's a link to my current code: https://pastebin.com/Lduz6GdD .

Comment: Ffmpeg isnt something that you install with pip, sorry. The first error is because the bot can't join multiple voice channels at once. It shouldn't cause a problem if you just catch the error. Here's an article on how to install ffmpeg: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows%3famp=1